# How to compare two arrays in python based on a value

Tags: python, arrays, compare

I am doing classification. I have two arrays, the first is 'Actual', and the second is 'Predicted'. I want to compare these two arrays. Suppose the first array is:

```
Actual = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

this tells us that the the first, second, and the last indexes are corresponding to class *1*.

The 'Predicted' array is:

```
Predicted = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
```

this tells us that the first and second indexes have been predicted accurately.

I want the output the tells us just those indexes that accurately predicted as *1*, like this:

```
output = [True, True, False, False, False]
```

**Update**
I want to evaluate just based on value *1*. If you see, the forth predicted value is accurately predicted by *3*, but I do not want that, because I want evaluate *1* value.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the expected behavior when the lengths are different?

Comment: What does it mean? Lengths are different?

Comment: You are comparing two lists. What if one is longer than the other?

Comment: Both of them have five elements!

Comment: yes, but that is only one example input. Surely if you were only processing a single example, you wouldn't write a program to do it. Assuming you process many different kinds of inputs, dealing with cases such as differing sizes is something that one must be capable of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presuming `length` of two lists are same:

```
>>> [(x == y == 1) for x, y in zip(Actual, Predicted)]
[True, True, False, False, False]
```

To feel safe;

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> [(x == y == 1) for x, y in izip_longest(Actual, Predicted, fillvalue=0)]
[True, True, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind using `numpy` library, then this can be done very easily -

```
In [10]: import numpy as np

In [11]: Actual=[1,1,2,3,1]

In [12]: ActualNp = np.array(Actual)

In [13]: Predicted=[1,1,1,3,3]

In [15]: PredictedNp = np.array(Predicted)

In [20]: (ActualNp == PredictedNp) & (PredictedNp == 1)
Out[20]: array([ True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

---

If not, assumming that you only want to check till the length of the smallest list (If they are of different lengths), you can use `zip` -

```
>>> Actual=[1,1,2,3,1]
>>> Predicted=[1,1,1,3,3]
>>> output = [a == b == 1 for a,b in zip(Actual,Predicted)]
>>> output
[True, True, False, False, False]
```

Comment: In you simulation, the forth element is True. It is by the value _3_. I do not want that. I want evaluate just based on _1_.

Comment: Updated the answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

A one liner simple approach would be

```
def get_prediction_results(prediction, actual, predicted):
 return [a == predicted[i] == prediction for i, a in enumerate(actual)]

>>> get_prediction_results(1, [1,1,2], [1,1,2])
[True, True, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, some array basics:

1. To get the number of elements in an array, use `len`:

   ```
    x = ['a', 'b', c']
    y = len(x)  # y == 3
   ```
2. To access the `i`th element of an array, use `[]`:

   ```
    x = ['a','b', 'c']
    y = x[1]  # y == 'b'
   ```
3. To obtain an iterator with values 0, 1, ..., n-1 ,use `range(n)`:

   ```
    x = list(range(3))  # x = [0, 1, 2]
   ```
4. To iterate through the values of an array, use `for ... in`:

   ```
    x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    for value in x:
       process(value)   # called for 'a', 'b', and 'c'
   ```
5. To compare items for equality, use `==` (or `!=` for inequality).

Putting this altogether,now:

```
def ComputeArrayDifference(a, b):
   alen = len(a)
   blen = len(b)
   if alen != blen:
      raise DifferingSizesException('Inputs have different sizes', a, b)
   result = []
   for i in range(alen):
      result.append(a[i] == b[i])
   return result
```